# Android JPEG to Bitmap = reduction in size

Tags: android, bitmap, arrays, jpeg

I noticed that after I converted my jpeg file into a bitmap the size drops almost by half, is this normal? I doing something like this:

```
    bmp1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            + "/Test/test" + System.currentTimeMillis()
                            + ".jpg");
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
    System.out.println(byteArray.length);
```

Comment: You seem to be decompressing a jpeg and compressing it back to jpeg... so if it's smaller you must be compressing at a lower quality than the original.

Comment: Although the other answers are right if the decoded bitmap was originally taken with a camera or other digital device decoding the image and recompressing it would remove all Exif data which can be up to 65,535 bytes. Just something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is decoding a jpeg into a bitmap and then re-compressing it into a jpeg again. The re-compression is likely to be reducing the file size, at the cost of also reducing the quality of the image.

Jpeg compression (even at quality 100) is not lossless.